# Background-Picture leaves white space underneath on mobile

Tags: html, css, background, whitespace

I created a website which basically  consists of a button  and everytime that you click on the button a sentence appears above it.
As Background I´ve set a picture. On Mobile I have the Problem that when a long sentence appears the content gets stretched so much that you have to scroll to reach the bottom of the page and at the bottom of the page appears a blank space underneath the picture. This whitespace doesnt appear in the developer tool though, just on my real phone.

So far I´ve been searching quite some time looking for a solution but i didnt find one. I though about disabling background-repeat: no-repeat; in media query but this would have unnice side effects.

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```
body {
    background-image: url('../Images/BG.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 125%;
    font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```
This is the HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0>   
</head>

<body >
<div id="main">
    <header class="header">
        <h1> Generator<span style="color:red">.com</span> </h1>
    </header>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <article id="spruchErstellen">
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="mainButton">
        <button class="button" onclick="neuerSpruch()">Go!</button>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="space">
</div>

    <footer id="mainFooter">
        <p>Copyright &copy 2019; All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the background-picture to allways fill the whole screen and to have no white spaces.

Greetings and thanks for your help.

Comment: try adding min-height: 100%; and height: auto; to body element

Comment: It´s not working :(

Comment: it would be better if you can provide your html code, just add it to your post, i will be able to help you better

Comment: Done! The "space" class is to make sure that the button doesnt get stuck inside the footer (because the positions is fixed.) Still didnt have time to implement a sticky one :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem as i guess is happening because of your content overflowing its container block, so the body shows the white extra space on the bottom because text took more space than it should,one of the solutions that i found to your problem is by setting your vertical overflow to auto using `overflow-y:auto`

```css
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow-y:auto;
 
}
body {
    background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-abstracto-acuarela-efecto-grunge_1340-4291.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 125%;
    font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0>   
</head>

<body >
<div id="main">
    <header class="header">
        <h1> Generator<span style="color:red">.com</span> </h1>
    </header>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <article id="spruchErstellen">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas egestas justo sit amet cursus tempus. Ut nec ligula vestibulum, aliquet tellus ac, pellentesque dolor. Fusce egestas congue nibh vel ultrices. Duis mollis arcu at sollicitudin tempus. Nam sed felis quis ligula dictum fermentum. Sed eget arcu sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec leo tellus, tempus faucibus arcu sit amet, tempor dignissim purus. Etiam rutrum fermentum accumsan. Sed interdum libero in laoreet aliquam. Integer sed dolor enim. Fusce aliquam ullamcorper dictum. Sed vehicula euismod felis, ornare condimentum metus dictum vel. Nam vestibulum ante eget ipsum efficitur pellentesque. Aliquam ac facilisis magna, eget rutrum erat. Pellentesque at quam ut metus pellentesque vulputate in ut eros.

Nam varius fermentum felis vel fringilla. Aliquam et sapien accumsan, viverra leo vel, iaculis nunc. Nullam vehicula cursus orci in malesuada. Quisque lacinia metus non lectus elementum, vel commodo augue blandit. Mauris dictum odio ut purus mattis rhoncus. Nam auctor consequat risus auctor euismod. Morbi aliquam eros nisl, in egestas tortor feugiat a. Morbi viverra nec mauris sed tempus. Cras blandit sagittis eros.

Aenean tempor risus odio, ut pretium massa mollis sed. Duis finibus justo non sem volutpat convallis. Donec rutrum nec lectus vitae iaculis. Aenean vitae tellus tristique, porta turpis nec, volutpat sem. Aliquam molestie scelerisque arcu in auctor. Nam suscipit est at est dictum maximus. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus eget mattis mauris, nec bibendum arcu. Cras ornare egestas eleifend. Integer semper elementum euismod. Sed a ligula risus. Fusce commodo sem sit amet malesuada blandit. Donec at justo et metus viverra aliquam eget sit amet turpis.

Integer ligula tellus, accumsan volutpat risus vitae, suscipit accumsan neque. Quisque sed efficitur urna. Nullam mollis ultricies enim, vitae interdum ipsum consequat consectetur. Phasellus tincidunt nunc ut nisi ullamcorper, in laoreet erat mollis. Vivamus a semper orci, sed vestibulum risus. Aenean ultrices quam tristique vestibulum vulputate. Praesent rutrum tempor libero, vitae sollicitudin tellus iaculis sit amet. Proin vulputate tellus tellus, sit amet dignissim sem venenatis sed. Pellentesque cursus lorem eu mauris malesuada scelerisque. Integer quis pulvinar urna. Aenean vitae porta ex, sit amet hendrerit lorem. Mauris dictum magna vitae imperdiet placerat.

Duis consectetur nec sem et hendrerit. Fusce ut porttitor arcu. Curabitur condimentum volutpat congue. Phasellus mauris dolor, commodo id felis sit amet, ornare imperdiet ante. Integer dignissim elit sit amet magna rutrum, vitae interdum dolor dignissim. Phasellus vulputate ac quam non porta. Nam viverra sapien vel metus consequat, vitae rutrum risus posuere. Fusce nec pellentesque sapien. Curabitur non efficitur nunc, at sodales sapien. Donec vulputate, tellus id rhoncus euismod, mauris lacus imperdiet urna, non ornare risus quam a diam. Maecenas sit amet libero ante. Aliquam non mauris a risus vehicula imperdiet. Donec volutpat euismod vulputate. Morbi nec egestas lectus, a aliquet nisi.
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="mainButton">
        <button class="button" onclick="neuerSpruch()">Go!</button>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="space">
</div>

    <footer id="mainFooter">
        <p>Copyright &copy 2019; All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

PS: the background image and the text are just for demonstration.